# How to create Tree like structure in JSF?

Tags: jsf-2

In JSF, how to make tree structure(left side) as links of diff files. 
On clicking them that link should open in same window in another panel(right side)?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at Primefaces's [treeTable](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/treeTableHome.jsf).

Comment: this is not like I actually want.

Comment: Do you have an example, something similar of what you want to implement?

Comment: consider there are two frames in one window.
On left side there are link for diff files in hierachial form.
When I'll click on any of those links then it should open on right side frame.